# Pandas: Iterate on a column one row at a time to automate a google search?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, automation

I am trying to automate 100 google searches (one per individual String in a row and return urls per each query) on a specific column in a csv (via python 2.7); however, I am unable to get Pandas to read the row contents to the Google Search automater.

*GoogleSearch source = https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/

Overall, I can print Urls successfully for a query when I utilize the following code:

```
from google import search

query = "apples"
for url in search(query, stop=5, pause=2.0):
    print(url)
```

However, when I add Pandas ( to read each "query") the rows are not read -> queried as intended.  **I.E. "data.irow(n)" is being queired instead of the row contents, one at a time.**

```
 from google import search
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

query_performed = 0
querying = True
query = 'data.irow(n)'

#read the excel file at column 2 (i.e. "Fruit")
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\query_results.csv', header=0, sep=',', index_col= 'Fruit')

# need to specify "Column2" and one "data.irow(n)" queried at a time
while querying: 
    if query_performed <= 100:
        print("query") 
        query_performed +=1
    else:
        querying =  False
    print("Asked all 100 query's")


#prints initial urls for each "query" in a google search
for url in search(query, stop=5, pause=2.0):
    print(url)
```

Incorrect output I receive at the command line:

```
query
Asked all 100 query's
query
Asked all 100 query's
Asked all 100 query's
http://www.irondata.com/
http://www.irondata.com/careers
http://transportation.irondata.com/
http://www.irondata.com/about
http://www.irondata.com/public-sector/regulatory/products/versa
http://www.irondata.com/contact-us
http://www.irondata.com/public-sector/regulatory/products/cavu
https://www.linkedin.com/company/iron-data-solutions
http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Iron-Data-Reviews-E332311.htm
https://www.facebook.com/IronData
http://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=35267805
http://www.indeed.com/cmp/Iron-Data
http://www.ironmountain.com/Services/Data-Centers.aspx
```

FYI: My Excel .CSV format is the following:

```
     B
1   **Fruit**
2   apples
2   oranges
4   mangos
5   mangos
6   mangos
...
101 mangos
```

Any advice on next steps is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with the urls that the search() returns?

Comment: Hi @Bob Haffner, Export the URL's to the CSV (in column C, D, E, ..) I am calling the "querys" from.  Thus, I will have the Search Terms, and on the same row, the corresponding URLs.  There might be a more efficient process for this, but this was my initial attempt.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: the stop parameter doesn't seem to limit the number of urls like i thought it would .  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I got.  Like I mentioned in my comment, I couldn't get the stop parameter to work like i thought it should.  Maybe i'm misunderstanding how its used.  I'm assuming you only want the first 5 urls per search.

a sample df

```
d = {"B" : ["mangos", "oranges", "apples"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then

```
stop = 5 
urlcols = ["C","D","E","F","G"]
# Here i'm using an apply() to call the google search for each 'row'
# and a list is built for the urls return by search()
df[urlcols] = df["B"].apply(lambda fruit : pd.Series([url for url in 
              search(fruit, stop=stop, pause=2.0)][:stop])) #get 5 by slicing
```

which gives you. Formatting is a bit rough on this

```
    B   C   D   E   F   G
0    mangos  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mango  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mango_(disambigua...   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangifera  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangifera_indica   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_mangosteen
1    oranges     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(fruit)     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_orange  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencia_orange    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutaceae   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_Orange
2    apples  https://www.apple.com/  http://desmoines.citysearch.com/review/692986920    http://local.yahoo.com/info-28919583-apple-sto...   http://www.judysbook.com/Apple-Store-BtoB~Cell...   https://tr.foursquare.com/v/apple-store/4b466b...
```

if you'd rather not specify the columns (i.e. ["C",D"..]) you could do the following.

```
df.join(df["B"].apply(lambda fruit : pd.Series([url for url in 
                     search(fruit, stop=stop, pause=2.0)][:stop])))
```

Comment: What is the name of the column that contains the search string?

Comment: Fruit - Is the name of column (located in : column B)  that contains the search strings.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not tracking you.  Would you mind posting the first few rows of your dataframe?  And what happens when you do print df.columns?

Comment: No problem, I just learned about importing an image, so screen shot the destination Excel file ("CSV (Excel) header:") and the Command Line error I receive when I print the updated code.  Thanks again, I really appreciate any additional assistance !

Comment: and added in my updated code.  Thanks again, and really appreciate any assistance resolving this!

Comment: It looks like you tried to edit my answer with your screenshots.  Please update your question instead.  and please print out your dataframe (not your excel file).  Thx!

Comment: Also, my sample data frame and code do work for you, correct?

Comment: Hi Bob, Your Sample data frame works (tested it in ipython).  I think there is a "data frame" confusion.  I am exclusively using the Excel  Column B (named: "Fruit") as my data frame/data source for the strings to query google.  I am adding in my updated code with #comments above each line to provide clarity. And editing my question. Currently, when I try to run it, the code runs >5mins w/o a response (error or inputing urls to the csv).  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, and thanks again! really appreciate it!

Comment: Got it to work!!!!  So So stoked to get this working, and with 5 hours to spare before work too!

Comment: Edited the first line to, "df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\ycjtv.csv', usecols=['fruit'])."  No edits to your; 2nd and third line, and for the last line: "df.to_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\ycjtv.csv', usecols=["fruit"])"  I was "http:503 blocked" once when I set, "pause=2," so changed it to 5.  Overall, exported over 4,000 links per search query's, thus, saved me days of mindless work!  Thanks again!!

Comment: Good deal.  Yeah, python data tools are amazing.  Haven't used that google search module before so I learned something too.